# Spring Requestbody JSON Deserializer not mapping the value

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-restcontroller

I have a  problem where JSON data is not mapping to the Entity and it displays "selectedOption" as null.

Following Spring REST Contoller Method saves the order.

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/saveOrder")
       public Long saveOrder(@RequestBody CustOrder order) {
          return shopService.saveCustomerOrder(order);
       }
```

Following is the JSON which is being sent to the method

```
 { 

   "order":[ 
      { 

         "selectedOption":{ 
            "id":6,
            "productOptionDescription":"Groß, Ø30cm:",
            "optionPrice":null,
            "optionPriceForSmall":null,
            "optionPriceForNormal":6.7,
            "optionPriceForFamily":null,
            "optionPriceForParty":null,
            "isDefault":true
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Entity CustOrder

```
   @Entity
public class CustOrder {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn( name="custorder_id")
    private Set<OrderItem> order=new HashSet<>();
}
```

Entity Order Item

```
   @Entity
public class OrderItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @OneToOne
    private ProductOption selectedOption;
}
```

I am struggling to understand why selectedOption is null.
Could someone help me with this.
Below is the screenshot from REST Controller Method (Eclipse)

[image: Eclipse_Debug_Mode]

Comment: lesnar, no idea why this is happening. Best I can suggest it to narrow it down to "selectedOptions". Meaning that remove all the fields and just try with "selectedOptions". And even remove internal fields from ProductOption and concentrate on 1 or 2 fields within it. You may need to annotate your class with `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`

Comment: @SupunWijerathne yes i am using spring-data-rest and the debug screenshot is from eclipse.

Comment: @SupunWijerathne the results are when i am sending the JSON using Postman (REST Client) to debug

Comment: @SupunWijerathne In REST Controller. Once my method is called. At very beginning of the method.

Comment: @SupunWijerathne   @RequestMapping(value = "/saveOrder")
    public Long saveOrder(@RequestBody CustOrder order) {
    return shopService.saveCustomerOrder(order);
    }

Comment: @lesnar did you just try making 'selectedOption' a String type and what if you send a String for 'selectedOption' from postman? still null?

Comment: I hope you aren't missing the `setter` for `selectedOption` in `OrderItem `